# I'm trying to copy the html website but whenever I try it only gives me a portion of it

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

```
import requests

webpage= requests.get('https://www.educationperfect.com/app/#/French/6696/999051/list-starter')

print(webpage.text)
```

Wondering how you can copy the full html of a website like when you ctrl+s on a page

Comment: You need to follow all image, script, stylesheet links and then likely access any Ajaxed content. In this case it's an Angular web app. So good luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pywebcopy` package like this

```py
from pywebcopy import save_webpage

url = 'https://google.com'
download_folder = '/path/to/downloads/'    

kwargs = {'bypass_robots': True, 'project_name': 'recognisable-name'}

save_webpage(url, download_folder, **kwargs)
```

You need just change `url` and `download_folder` and use it but first install `pywebcopy` like this

```
pip3 install pywebcopy
```

And that is a [link](https://pypi.org/project/pywebcopy/) for more info

Comment: You're welcome, if my answer helped you with your question, I would appreciate it if you choose it as the best answer as you wish.